# comparing array with int in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

I'm reading through the drupal_bootstrap code at: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7 to try to understand how to bootstrap drupal code. I have experience in other languages but not php. This line of code below puzzles me, because $phases is an array, and everything else is int. What does it mean when it compares array with an int?

```
while ($phases && $phase > $stored_phase && $final_phase > $stored_phase) {
      $current_phase = array_shift($phases);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I have a very basic question..what does it mean to bootstrap drupal code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you do have another question, please do open another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php basic comparison, an array with elements==`True` and an empty array==`False`.
`array_shift()` reduce the size of array.

So, in your example, the loop reduce the size of `$phases` until the `$phases` is empty.
(better: until `$phases` is empty or one of the other conditions are `False`)

#### Edit:

There is not a comparison between array and integer, the condition is:
ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY **AND** INT > INT **AND** INT > INT.

#### Edit 2:

Please note that there are a sort of incongruity in php [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) comparison:

```
array() == False
''      == False
0       == False
```

but:

```
''      == 0
array() != ''   <------ !!!!
array() != 0    <------ !!!!
```

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

it does not compare array to int.
the first part of the condition where it uses `$phases` just checks that it has a value.

Definition of bootstrap in Computing:

> a technique of loading a program into a computer by means of a few
>   initial instructions which enable the introduction of the rest of the
>   program from an input device.